# State Column mapping in tbl_TestRun

Tags: tfs

I tried to get some infos from the table tbl_TestRun.

unfortunatly I did not found a documentation for the different states. The column contains values like 3 or 4. But I need to knwo what value stand for what state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state ID just the ID of state and correspond to the state name  which you can find in `tbl_TestRun` such as  below picture
 [image]

Add all related state  and state name as below:

```
SELECT 0 AS [StateID], 'Unspecified' AS [StateName]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS [OutcomeId], 'To Be Determined (1)' AS [StateName]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS [StateID], 'In Progress' AS [StateName]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS [StateID], 'Completed' AS [StateName]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 AS [StateID], 'Aborted' AS [StateName]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 AS [OutcomeId], 'To Be Determined (5)' AS [StateName]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 6 AS [StateID], 'Needs Investigation' AS [StateName]
```

Comment: thankgs for the info. But I didn't found the information `tbl_TestRun` but `[TFS_Warehouse].[dbo].[DimTestRun]`